# how to compile libraries for the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, libraries

I have a library of C code which has an abstraction layer and I wish to port to the Linux kernel.

Googling for "compiling library for Linux kernel" is useless, because all you find are hits for "compiling Linux kernel".

Does anyone have pointers to explanations/descriptions/etc on how to compile libraries for the kernel?

Is the question even correct?  does the kernel have a notion of libraries?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to learn is to [create a kernel module](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/).  You have a choice of making the library a part of that module (there would be nothing Linux kernel specific about that), or build it as a separate module with exported symbols, allowing reuse.

For the vast majority of tasks I would recommend looking for a solution completely or mostly in userland (keeping the library and all code that uses it in a regular process) and run only the absolutely necessary code, if any remains, in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks!  (regarding user-mode; this is a library of lock-free data structures - the kernel port is so they are available to kernel mode developers)

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure I *do* want a module.  I want the data structure APIs to be available to the kernel proper.  There is for example I understand an implementation of RCU in the kernel.  Where is this implemented?  is this in a module?

Comment: Search the source.  It is not a module.  Tips what to search for are in the kernel source as well: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/RCU/rcu.txt

Comment: @BlankXavier - The reason why I am suggesting the modular way is that it will make your code much easier to develop, and will not commit everyone else to its presence in the kernel.  Modules can be loaded and unloaded without a reboot.

Comment: oh FFS... I can't write "@Jirka:" at the beginning of a comment - for some reason it disappears

Comment: right, but I'm thinking if you want to use data structure APIs and you need to load them via module, then all the code which has to run to get the kernel to the point it can load modules cannot use those data structures.

Comment: sigh - bloody SO admin - stop messing up the site!

Comment: I earlier found that link to RCU documentation, but it didn't help - it doesn't say if RCU is a module or not.

Comment: I'm coming to the view a module with exported APIs is a good place to start; I think getting into the kernel will be a whole 'nother kettle of fish.  At least it will be useful for module developers.

Comment: If you want to make some new data structures available, then why don't you do it like how current data structures are implemented - either the whole implementation is in a header file (list.h) or you have some functions that you export and have a header file which others can include (like mutex etc.). And you have a config option to compile the library into the kernel. Don't see how modules fit into all this.

Comment: @Omair - Modules make debugging much easier, unless you really love reboots with every recompilation.